# Controll vms remotely

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'd like to manage my vm via ssh connection, for e.g. start vm in headless mode or just list available vms but i seems not to work. 
When i issue command

`VBoxManage startvm MyVM --type headless`

i get an error:

`could not find a registered machine named MyVM`

and  VBoxManage list vms returns nothing
All that works when i issue the commsands locally from Windows cmd console.

Comment: Are you the same user under CMD and SSH ?

Comment: No. But for some reason i can't login as the user i use under CMD. So my question is how to determinate what permissions the alternative (SSH) user ought to have to make it to work?

Comment: The registration of VMs is a property of the user - so user A won't see the VMs of user B. You would need to register the VM as your ssh user and either it already works or you need to work from there (with a different error message).